# Selecting elements from an array based on another array values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, match

Sorry for this basic question... I am relatively new to JS.

I have two arrays and want to select values from one based on the values of the other.

For example, if I have

```
var student = [10, 11, 21, 30, 31, 14];
var class   = [1,   1,  2,  3,  3,  1];
```

How would I proceed (ideally with filter and/or map) to get the list of student numbers in `class = 1`, for example.

I know how I would do it with a for-loop and push() function, but I think there should be a more elegant/concise way to perform that task in a single line command with map, filter or other functions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A `for` loop sounds pretty elegant to me tbh.

Comment: what would be the list of resulting student numbers in `class = 1`? perhaps demonstrate what you have tried with the for-loop and `push` approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering the students by checking the index in the other array would be pretty simple:

```js
var student = [10, 11, 21, 30, 31, 14];
var classes   = [1,   1,  2,  3,  3,  1];

console.log(
  student.filter((_, i) => classes[i] === 1)
);
```

Keep in mind you cannot use `class` as a variable name - it's reserved. Use something else.

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved word in `JavaScript`. To achieve the expected output, you can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return elements where `classes[index]` have the value of 1:

```js
const students = [10, 11, 21, 30, 31, 14]; 
const classes =  [1,  1,  2,  3,  3,  1];

const getStudentsInClassOne = (arr=[]) => {
  if(arr.length !== classes.length) return;
  return arr.filter((e,index) => classes[index]===1);
}

console.log( getStudentsInClassOne(students) );
```